# Nav Menu Over Homepage Banner Area

Tags: css

I would like to know the best way to implement a header/nav that sits over the top of a home page banner div so that the banner's background shows through the header. The content of the header would be located in a template file, while the content of the homepage banner would be outside the template. Because of this, I don't think I can/should nest the header inside the banner. Also, because I'm using a template, the same header will be used on pages other than the home page that don't have a banner.

So far I've got something that sort of works, but I had to do some things that seem a bit inelegant:

1) I had to code the header after the banner. It's probably not a big deal, but I suppose it would be better for screen readers if the first part came first and the second part second.

2) In order for the content text to clear the absolutely positioned banner, I put a bunch of padding at the top of the #content div. But unless the banner is a fixed height, the amount of padding required will vary. Also, on pages that don't have a banner, I'd have to remove that padding entirely.

What's the better way?

```css
body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    margin: 0;
   }
   
   #banner {
       background-image: url('http://toprival.com/temp/jsfiddle/background.jpg');
       margin: 0;
       padding: 100px 30px 30px 30px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%;
       background-size:cover;
   }
   
   #banner h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
   }
   
   header {
       position: absolute;
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       right:0;
       padding: 30px;
   }
   
   #menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   }
   
   #menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
   }
   
   #menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
   }
      
      #menu li a:hover {
    color: aqua;
   }
   
   .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
   }
   
   #content {
    padding: 260px 30px 30px 30px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="banner">
   <h1>Supacool Website Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  
  <header>
   <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  
  <div id="content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I guess i would seperate header from banner. Put it outside and add it a position absolute with z-index : 1 so it comes over your content. How does it sounds

Comment: "The content of the header would be located in a template file, while the content of the homepage banner would be outside the template." What kind of template is this? Is it an include or something?

Comment: It's for a Joomla site, so it's the main index.php file.